# Serializing and Deserializing a tree structure with Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, data-structures, tree, jackson

I have a tree structure with the following objects that I need to serialize and deserialize using Jackson but cannot figure out how to do it.

#### `Type`

`Type` has a name and a version. It may also have a parent and sub-types.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "name")
final class Type {

    private final PrefixedName name;
    private final Integer version;
    private final Set<Type> subTypes = new HashSet<>();
    private final Type parent;
    private final PrefixedName parentName;


    Type(final PrefixedName name, final Integer version) {
        this(name, version, null);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    Type(@JsonProperty("name") @JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = PrefixedNameKeyDeserializer.class) final PrefixedName name,
            @JsonProperty("typeVersion") final Integer version, @JsonProperty("parent") final Type parent) {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);

        Preconditions.checkArgument(version > 0, "Version number must be positive");
        this.version = version;

        this.parent = parent;
        if (parent != null) {
            this.parentName = parent.getName();
            parent.addSubType(this);
        } else {
            this.parentName = null;
        }
    }

    // Other methods to add sub-types; and getters for all properties omitted

}
```

#### `Model`

`Model` contains the root of the tree – a `Type` and a version.

```
final class Model {

    private final Integer version;
    private final Type root;

    @JsonCreator
    Model(@JsonProperty("modelVersion") final Integer version, @JsonProperty("root") final Type root) {
        this.version = version;
        this.root = root;
    }
```

Using Jackson's `ObjectMapper` the serialization looks as I'd expect:

```
{
   "root":{
      "parent":null,
      "name":{
         "localName":"Base",
         "prefix":"schema"
      },
      "subTypes":[
         {
            "parent":{
               "localName":"Base",
               "prefix":"schema"
            },
            "name":{
               "localName":"Person",
               "prefix":"schema"
            },
            "subTypes":[
               {
                  "parent":{
                     "localName":"Person",
                     "prefix":"schema"
                  },
                  "name":{
                     "localName":"employee",
                     "prefix":"schema"
                  },
                  "subTypes":[

                  ],
                  "version":1
               }
            ],
            "version":1
         },
         {
            "parent":{
               "localName":"Base",
               "prefix":"schema"
            },
            "name":{
               "localName":"organisation",
               "prefix":"schema"
            },
            "subTypes":[

            ],
            "version":1
         },
         {
            "parent":{
               "localName":"Base",
               "prefix":"schema"
            },
            "name":{
               "localName":"CreativeWork",
               "prefix":"schema"
            },
            "subTypes":[
               {
                  "parent":{
                     "localName":"CreativeWork",
                     "prefix":"schema"
                  },
                  "name":{
                     "localName":"Journal",
                     "prefix":"schema"
                  },
                  "subTypes":[

                  ],
                  "version":1
               },
               {
                  "parent":{
                     "localName":"CreativeWork",
                     "prefix":"schema"
                  },
                  "name":{
                     "localName":"Book",
                     "prefix":"schema"
                  },
                  "subTypes":[

                  ],
                  "version":1
               }
            ],
            "version":1
         }
      ],
      "version":1
   },
   "version":8
}
```

Note the annotation on the `Type` class `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "name")` means that the `parent` property is written using just the `name` property - this is to prevent infinite recursion and a `StackOverflowException` – if there is a better way to do this I would be happy to change.

However the deserialization is failing with a `NullPointerException` on the line setting the `name` property in `Type`:

```
this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
```

I've debugged through the code and have seen that Jackson is capturing the two properties of `PrefixedName` (class shown below) for the parent as "unknown" properties – I'm not sure if this is related to the problem but it may be useful.

#### `PrefixedName`

This is a simple [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto) class of two String properties with Jackson annotations:

```
@AutoValue
@SuppressWarnings("squid:S1610")
@JsonDeserialize(builder = AutoValue_PrefixedName.Builder.class)
abstract class PrefixedName {

    static Builder builder() {
        return new AutoValue_PrefixedName.Builder();
    }

    @JsonProperty
    abstract String prefix();

    @JsonProperty
    abstract String localName();

    @AutoValue.Builder
    abstract static class Builder {

        @JsonProperty
        abstract Builder prefix(final String prefix);

        @JsonProperty
        abstract Builder localName(final String localName);

        abstract PrefixedName build();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.